# How to match a string using a list of characters in SQLite

Tags: regex, sqlite, sql-like

i have a problem working with `SQLite` especially `like` statement. I want to retrieve data from a table where a `varchar` column is composed of list of characters given by the user.

For example:

If the user passes in `awnxov` I would want words that have those letters to match, like `won` and `wax` that might be in my table.

Comment: Could you provide an example or perhaps something you have already tried?

Comment: i want to check if this word 'won' is composed from the characters that this word hold 'awnxov',the word 'won' is stored in the database
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment, you want to provide a list of letters and find all words that match. You can't do this with `LIKE`.

You can, however, use `REGEXP`.  But to use it, you'll need to install a regexp lib or write your own regexp function and provide a callback.

If you are using Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3-pcre
```

Or you can install from the github page [here](https://github.com/ralight/sqlite3-pcre).

Then when you run sqlite, you need to execute to load the `regexp()` function:

```
.load /usr/lib/sqlite3/pcre.so
```

(or wherever the lib is)

Finally you can do something like:

```
SELECT word
FROM   table
WHERE  word REGEXP '^[awnxov]+$'
```

Or any other PCRE that you think matches.

This probably won't perform well.  It'll be a scan of all the data most likely.  Depending on how much data there is, and how many letters you receive as input, you might want to just create an index and search for each two letter combinations and do a check in code to see if it passes or not.

Good luck